# An error occurred while mounting

Tags: boot, usb

Well I'm elbow deep in new territory, built my first PC and decided to load it with Ubuntu.

I have no idea where I am...

Here's the skinny.

This is my stuff:

- ASRock 970 Extreme3.0 R2.0
- AMD FX 4130 quad core
- Radeon SAPPHIRE HD7870
- Seagate Barracuda 2TB 7200rpm SATA3
- 2 x 4GB Kingston DDR3 HyperX Genesis 1600 MHz
- Corsair 650W

Made a USB boot drive with that linux pen drive installer (tried 13.10, then tried 12.04.3).

v13.10 gives me a black/purple screen after the load screen.  Running the "check disc for defects" showed there were two files with errors.  So I loaded v12.04.3 and then it said there were 3 files with errors.  I tried to run before installing but the next message was

"an error occurred while mounting"

So.  Where do I start?  Is it possible my HDD is DOA?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference but Im trying to boot with a USB3.0 on a 3.0 port

Comment: It does. Try disabling USB3.0 or plug it into a 2.0 port

Comment: Tried with 2.0, same problem.

Comment: Live Ubuntu should leave the fingers from your disks as long as you don't tell him so... What happens if you unplug all HDD's temporarily?

Comment: It says failed to mount

Comment: You could try creating the bootstick with UNetBootin instead of PenDriveLinux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating the bootstick with UNetBootin instead of PenDriveLinux.
UNetBootIn is the least buggy bootstick creator I know.